# Can be Kinectimals Unleashed actually won?

Tags: pc, kinectimals-unleashed

Does this game has an ending (scripted sequence when something happens) or is it a neverending earn-purchase-train-improve cycle?

I have achieved maximum trainer experience level (lvl 50) and one of my pets achieved maximum strength, endurance and cleanliness levels (30, 30, 30). What is still ahead:

- purchasing of toys, having 50% of all earns an achievement
- purchasing of cubs, having 50% of all earns an achievement
- purchasing access to unvisited locatios, having them all earns few achievements (they are pretty expensive though and it is doubtful whether they are worthy to strive for)

Is there any "you win" screen to expect? :)

Comment: I really don't believe so. My understanding of it is it's an overly elaborate tamagotchi.

Comment: @Ben - previous Kinectimals games (*Kinectimals* and *Kinectimals now with bears*) had their storylines and endings, they can be found on youtube etc. But there is too few information about this one.

Comment: Well there you go :) My knowledge of this game is minimal at best, hence why I didn't answer it.

Comment: A stroll through the achievements usually gives you an indication. If there is no achievements for completing the game, chances are that won't happen.